# Intuition from Hopf lemma (boundary point lemma )

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

Consider the classical boundary point lemma:

Let $L$ be an elliptic operator.

**Boundary Point Lemma** Suppose $\Omega$ has the interior sphere property and that $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\bar\Omega)$ satisfies $Lu \geq 0$ in $\Omega$. Assume $u$ attains its non negative maximum at $x_0 \in \bar \Omega$. Then $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and for any outward direction $v$ at $x_0$ to $\partial \Omega$
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}(x_0) > 0$$
unless $u$ is constant in $\bar\Omega$.

Now my question is:
could I say that the gradient $Du(x_0)$ has the opposite direction of inner normal to $\partial\Omega$ at $x_0$?

I thought this from the fact that $(Du(x_0),v)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}(x_0)$. Now, if what I am said before is not true, one can find an outward direction such that $0>(Du(x_0),v)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}(x_0)$, so one have a contraddiction.

Is this true or I am wrong in some steps?